# Common dependencies in several Services

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, service-layer

My goal is to have the same dependencies in different Services.

I need it because in some cases I use the same entity for different Services. Example:

```
...
$user = $this->userRepository->find(123);
$this->userService->doSomeWithUserRepository(); # here using $user entity
$this->commentService->doSomeWithUserRepository(); # and ! here too the same
...
```

Here is an example how I achievied it now:

```
public function __construct(
    UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository,
    FileRepositoryInterface $fileRepository,
    CommentRepositoryInterface $commentRepository
  ) {
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    $this->fileRepository = $fileRepository;
    $this->commentRepository = $commentRepository;

    $this->userService = new UserService(
      $userRepository, $fileRepository, $commentRepository
    );

    $this->commentService = new CommentService(
      $userRepository, $fileRepository, $commentRepository
    );

    $this->middleware(...
    ...
  }
```

So, as you can see with this approach the constructor can be really **big and ugly** if each service will have a lot of dependencies.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
public function __construct(
    UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository,
    FileRepositoryInterface $fileRepository,
    CommentRepositoryInterface $commentRepository
    UserService $userService,
    CommentService $commentService
  ) {
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    $this->fileRepository = $fileRepository;
    $this->commentRepository = $commentRepository;
    $this->userService = $userService;
    $this->commentService = $commentService;

    $this->middleware(...
    ...
  }
```

I'll be glad to hear any help/hint/remark.
Maybe am I using wrong logic or something?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding dependency injection a little. First rule of that is to never use the `new` keyword.

If you have the UserService.php as follows, then it will automatically load repositories through the container.

```
class UserService
{
    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository, FileRepository $fileRepository, CommentRepository $commentRepository)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Therefor you can do as follows. This code will resolve the `UserService` and since all the Repositories are in the constructor, it will also resolve them.

```
public function __construct(UserService $userService) {
    ...
}
```

If you whatever reason, wants to have the same dependency injection functionality without a constructor you can use `app()` or `resolve()` to do the same.

```
resolve(UserService::class); // will resolve user service with it 3 repositories
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But it doesn't resolve my issue case. I want that in my services entities was the same.

Comment: Please elaborate. This is the way to do it, if you want to work with the container :)

Comment: Oh, I've made mistakes when to post the question for the first time. 
I've updated it. Please, check it.

Comment: You write "I want to achieve something like this:" how is not my example close to this?

Comment: If you'll be using several Services with the same dependencies, then entities from repositories won't be the same. Please, check the first code attachment that I've added.

Comment: But what you want to achieve is exactly what i have shown? i will leave it for now, this is a mess tbh, your architecture seems a little bit aggressive if you need so many dependencies